# Python: how to fit ODE systems with hierarchical function inside to multiple data

Tags: python, curve-fitting, ode, differential-equations, lmfit

I am working on some biological data to model the behavior of bacterial systems, using GFP fluorescence protein and cell growth data. Basically they are two different datasets that are measured over the course of 24 hours, and I have them in two different dataframes (assume the names are `fdata` and `odata`).

Now, I have a system ODE model that I need to fit to both of these data:

```
[dGFP] = a + (d + g(OD))[GFP]    #g(OD) is basically another ODE to describe the growth rate
[dOD] = m * (1 - (OD/n)) * OD    #this represents g(OD)
```

I have wrote a Python function to parameter estimation on the growth data as follows:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from scipy.integrate import odeint
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit

odata = df3[df3.columns[col]] #reading growth data
t = list(range(0, len(odata.index)))

def testfunc(t, k1, k2):
    
    def cell_density_model(OD, t, m, n):
        dOD = m * (1 - (OD[0]/n)) * OD[0]
        return dOD
    
    Ca0 = np.abs(odata[0])
    rates = (k1, k2)
    Casol = odeint(cell_density_model, Ca0, t, rates)
    return Casol[:,0]

k_fit, kcov = curve_fit(testfunc, t, odata)
print(k_fit)
fit = testfunc(t, k_fit[0], k_fit[1])

plt.plot(t, odata, '+', label='data')
plt.plot(t, fit, '-', label='fit')
plt.legend(loc='best')
plt.show()
```

And I have a different function for fitting the protein data (not working code). What I wanted to do is basically to integrate them together, but I am now sure how to do it.

```
def fitfunc(t, xa, xd, xCa0):
    
    a = xa
    d = xd
    Ca0 = xCa0
    
    def andGate(y, t):
        
        [GFP] = y
        OD = testfunc(t, amr, amc)       #this seems problematic
        GFP_ = a - (d + OD) * GFP 
        return [GFP_]
    
    Casol = odeint(andGate, Ca0, t)
    return Casol[:,0]

def modelfit(t, xa, xd):
    return fitfunc(t, xa, xd, Ca0)

fdata = df2[df2.columns[col]]    #reading fluorescence data
t = list(range(0, len(fdata.index)))

Ca0 = np.abs(fdata[0])
params, cov = curve_fit(modelfit, t, fdata)
fit = fitfunc(t, *params, Ca0)
print(params)

plt.plot(t, fdata, 'x', label='data')
plt.plot(t, fit, '-', label='fit')
plt.legend(loc='best')
plt.show()
```

Does anyone have any idea how to do this? I have tried `curve_fit` from scipy, and `lmfit`. I am open to rewrite my function using different library as well as long as in Python. Any help will be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: You use `.flatten()` or `np.concatenate` to make one data series out of 2 or more lists. It is only a suggestion that `xdata` has the same length as `ydata`, `xdata` could be an empty dummy object.

Comment: @LutzLehmann I was thinking about doing that, but then how/where do I split the data again into original lists? because I think when I call ```curve_fit``` it only passes one dataset to fit. Did I not get what you meant correctly?

Comment: If I get it right, you just have a set of coupled ODEs. That is couvered by the [`odeint`-example](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.integrate.odeint.html) isn't it?